# Gradle fails to find custom plugin when building in the CI but succeeds locally

Tags: kotlin, gradle, continuous-integration, maven-plugin

I have a gradle kotlin project that uses a Gradle plugin I wrote and published to a Maven repo. When I build locally my project gradle succeded to download the plugin packages from Github. When I build using the github CI it fails giving the following massage:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.example.plugins.Testing', version: '0.1.4'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.example.plugins.Testing:com.example.plugins.Testing.gradle.plugin:0.1.4')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://maven.pkg.github.com/my_org/infra)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    maven2(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)
    Google
```

I tried building using the CI including a Maven Repo I wrote and that worked fine, suggesting the authentication and the workflow are most likely correct.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.